# gulp inject pointing to destination folder

Tags: gulp, gulp-inject

I am using coffee script to generate my js and i am ok with generating it to dist folder from src folder.
now trying to autoload those files using gulp-inject and following is my code.

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('inject', function () {
  var target = gulp.src('./dist/index.html');
  // It's not necessary to read the files (will speed up things), we're only after their paths: 
  var sources = gulp.src(['./scripts/**/*.js','./partials/**/*.js', './styles/**/*.css'], {read: false},{relative: false});

  return target.pipe(plugins.inject(sources))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

The resultant output is coming in
**dist/index.html**

```
<!--inject:js--><script src="/dist/scripts/app.js"></script><script src="/dist/scripts/config.js"></script><script src="/dist/scripts/routes.js"></script><script src="/dist/partials/home/home.controller.js"></script><!--endinject-->
```

I want it to be like scripts/routes.js and scripts/config.js

As i use browser-sync, its pointing to dist folder which is the root folder. I tried on combinations but nothing fitted out. Point me through the right code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put `{ relative: false }` on gulp.src(). This  [option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject#options-relative) belongs in inject()

```
    var sources = gulp.src(['./scripts/**/*.js', './partials/**/*.js', './styles/**/*.css'], { read: false });

    return target.pipe(plugins.inject(sources, { relative: false }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```

If relative doesn't do what you need see [Clarifying injected paths](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject/wiki/Clarifying-injected-paths) for other options.